# How to handle addEventListener and attachEvent conflict?

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

I'm creating a drop or click file upload. I'm having an issue handling the difference between the click & the drop since one use addEventListener and the other one use normal javascript method.

**HTML**

```
<input id="imageLoader" type="file" name="imageLoader">
```

**Javascript :**

```
  var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');

  /* console shows : ..change { 
    target: <input#imageLoader>, 
    isTrusted: true, 
    currentTarget: <input#imageLoader>, 
    eventPhas... } 
  */
  imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

  /* console shows : undefined */
  imageLoader.onchange = function(){
    handleImage();
  };

  function handleImage(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
```

How can I show the same values as the `addeventlistener` method using the other way ?

Comment: Well, how about passing the parameter through you anonymous function?

Comment: Or just do `imageLoader.onchange = handleImage;` directly

Comment: @Satpal It has to be in the function

Comment: `addEventListener` is the normal JavaScript method.

Comment: @Satpal because I have to check wether it's an image or not before running the handleImage function, so there's a bunch of code before

Comment: @Lindow Why do you think it has to be?

Comment: @Satpal great :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `addEventListener` accepts a callback function in which you can call any code you want.

So instead of just passing your `handleImage` function directly as a callback you can create a callback function that calls your `handleImage` function.

```
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', function(e){
     //do whatever you want here
     handleImage()
}, false);
```

For attaching the event with `onchange` you can use the same approach :

```
imageLoader.onchange = function(event) { 
    //do whatever you want here
    handleImage(event); 
};
```

Comment: That achieves the opposite result of what the OP wants.

Comment: @Bergi My bad, I thought he was talking about `addEventListener`, but anyway it's the same approach